# Do I need to send two official copies of toefl/gre scores to a US school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, gre, language-exams, toefl

I'm applying two programs in different departments in one university simultaneously. One department has a department code and the other has not. Do I need to send two official copies of toefl/gre scores to the university?

Comment: Do they have different GRE institution codes? Do they require department codes?

Comment: @ff524 One department writes down department codes explicitly (doesn't say required) and the other does not write at all.

Answer (score 3):

Send the e-mail directly to the university asking for the related problem/confusion.
Every university is ready to help with these type of queries. 
Send one email to admission director, or call their admission office. You will get the best clarification directly from the source because admission director will be the person reviewing your application!